# reading from a NamedTemporaryFile in python

Tags: python, temporary-files

I am creating a tempFile and then adding text to it by opening it with an editor(so that user can enter his message), and then save it to read the text from save NamedTemporaryFile.

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
    f.close()
    if subprocess.call([editor.split(" ")[0], f.name]) != 0:
        raise IOError("{} exited with code {}.".format(editor.split(" ")[0], rc))
    with open(f.name) as temp_file:
        temp_file.seek(0)
        for line in temp_file.readlines():
            print line
```

But every time it is coming out to be blank. why is it so ?

Comment: What OS is this on? It works fine for me on Mac OS X.

Comment: Also works fine on Windows.

Comment: What editor? It could be that the editor forks into the background, so your subprocess.call()` returns early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SublimeText as the editor, you will need to pass in the `-w` or `--wait` argument to make sure that the Python program waits until you actually close SublimeText again.

Otherwise, you would just start to edit the file, and immediately try to read its contents which at that point are empty.

You could also verify that, by putting in a `print` before reading the file.

E.g.:

```
editor = ['/path/to/sublime_text', '-w']

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
    f.close()
    if subprocess.call(editor + [f.name]) != 0:
        raise IOError()

    # read file…
```

Comment: isn't it possible yo do without `'-w'` argument ?

Comment: No, because `subprocess.call` will immediately return.

Comment: then is there any other alternative then using subprocess call? should `subprocess.Popen` work ?

Comment: No, it applies to anything. If you start SublimeText from *anything* without passing `-w`, SublimeText *itself* will make sure that the process calling it won’t block itself.

Comment: so you mean all application will wait if `-w` flag is passed ?

Comment: No, that’s not what I said. I said, that SublimeText will never wait, unless you pass `-w` or `--wait`. Otherwise, it will detach itself from the calling process to make sure it runs independently. Not all programs do that, and others might have a similar parameter to prevent that from happening; and yes, it’s likely that the parameter will be different for other applications. So no, you can’t get a general way for every editor without also carrying the flag for each editor.

Comment: What you generally have to do is allow the user to specify their own command for editing, and the user specifies the necessary command line flags (if any) for his editor.

Comment: To be more accurate, you best update the comment
    # read file…
to
    # reopen and read file

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without editor interaction since I don't have enough information to mimic your editor setup.

```
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
    f.close()
    with open(f.name, f.mode) as fnew:
        # Replace with editor interaction
        fnew.write('test')
        fnew.seek(0)
        for line in fnew.readlines():
            print line
```

At least on my system and version (2.7.2), I had to make these changes to allow the file object to be properly reopened and interacted with, and it builds correctly in Sublime. f.name is the temporary file path, and f.mode is the mode used by the already closed file (in this case it should default to 'w+b').

Comment: on second attempt it opens the file with test written in it.